# SignalR and client data consistency

Tags: signalr

I'm about to implement a client check that warns if the data state is not as it should be. The server pushes data when it changes to the clients. Server always knows the current state. Is there anything in the SinglarR framework to help me write these checks? I guess it is necessary to write these checks (when using SignalrR and a push strategy) if consistency is important?

I'm thinking of adding a continous ID to all data entities send. Then both the client and server could hash the IDs and compare their state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SignalR helps with the communication channel, but the data validation is up to your app to handle.

Also if you want to know when something changed, rather than just accepting an unchanged copy from the client, you would need to impose that check. You could use the .Observable along with RX along with .DistinctUntilChanged to protect for this case.